# Python mapping char to integer

Tags: python, list, mapping

I got a shuffled list. How do I map it with number?

For example below:

```
list1('zyxwvutsrq')
```

How can I map so that `z=0, y=1, ...`

Currently I can map it like this

```
num1 = 0
num2 = 1

char1 = list[num1]
char2 = list[num2]

print(char1 , num1) # output = z
```

This would correctly give me the letter at the index. However, if I would like to do the same for larger sum for example a 4-digit number `4557` how can I print vuus as output without using dict or sets?
do I have to split `4557` 4-num and convert each back to char? Or is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Option 1 : With a Loop***

1. Loop on the number, and each iteration convert current digit to an index with `int(d)`
2. Fetch the letter of `s` at stage 1 index

```
s = 'zyxwvutsrq'

number = 4557

letters = ''
for d in str(number):
    letters += s[int(d)]

# 'vuus'
print(letters)
```

***Option 2 : One Liner***

Similiar to option 1, with the use of the `join` function that joins a list to a string.

```
magic = ''.join(s[int(d)] for d in str(number))
```